# Spring Boot Issue while starting Jetty Container

Tags: spring-boot, microservices

When I am starting the spring boot application, it is throwing the following exception.

I am not sure if the FAT jar includes servlet container that has anything related to OS related. Here is the exception I am getting while running the application:

```
    2016-04-04 15:42:55.146  INFO 10432 --- [           main] application
                   : Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2016-04-04 15:42:55.147  INFO 10432 --- [           main] o.e.jetty.server.handl
er.ContextHandler  : Stopped o.s.b.c.e.j.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext@1f144a2b{/,f
ile:/C:/Users/roopa_ranganath/AppData/Local/Temp/jetty-docbase.89466793494324913
0.8080/,UNAVAILABLE}
2016-04-04 15:42:55.154 ERROR 10432 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplica
tion               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Una
ble to start embedded Jetty servlet container
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletC
ontainer.start(JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.java:124) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEA
SE.jar!/:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationConte
xt.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:293) ~[sprin
g-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationConte
xt.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.REL
EASE.jar!/:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refres
h(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.
5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationConte
xt.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.j
ar!/:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.
java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(Sp
ringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java
:307) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java
:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java
:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at com.infosys.finanztools.Application.main(Application.java:13) [Finanz
ToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:11.2.6-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.
0_66]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.
0_66]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:
1.8.0_66]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner
.java:54) [FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:11.2.6-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_66]
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_66
]
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:27
7) ~[jetty-server-9.2.2.v20140723.jar!/:9.2.2.v20140723]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNet
workConnector.java:80) ~[jetty-server-9.2.2.v20140723.jar!/:9.2.2.v20140723]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java
:216) ~[jetty-server-9.2.2.v20140723.jar!/:9.2.2.v20140723]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLife
Cycle.java:68) ~[jetty-util-9.2.15.v20160210.jar!/:9.2.15.v20160210]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletC
ontainer.start(JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEA
SE.jar!/:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        ... 16 common frames omitted

2016-04-04 15:42:55.160  INFO 10432 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingA
pplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [jar:file:/D:/F
inanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.
6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.
6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-boot-starter-web-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/Fi
nanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-boot-starter-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar
!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-boot-1.3.3.
RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-
boot-autoconfigure-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-
SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/
FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/logback-classic-1.1.5.jar!/, jar:fi
le:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/logback-core-1.1.5.jar!/, ja
r:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.16.ja
r!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.
16.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/log4j-over-s
lf4j-1.7.16.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/sna
keyaml-1.16.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spr
ing-boot-starter-tomcat-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11
.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsS
ervices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.32.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/Fina
nzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.32.jar!/,
jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/tomcat-embed-websocke
t-8.0.32.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spring
-boot-starter-validation-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-1
1.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/Fina
nzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar!/, jar:f
ile:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.j
ar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/classmate-1.1.0.
jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/hibernate-core-
3.6.0.Final.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/ant
lr-2.7.7.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/common
s-collections-3.2.2.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!
/lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/li
b/hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServi
ces-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar!/, jar:file:/
D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/jta-1.1.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/Fina
nzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/finacle-11.2.6.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/Fina
nzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar!/, jar:file:/
D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar!/, j
ar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar!/, jar
:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/common-11.2.6.jar!/, jar:
file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/framework-11.2.6.jar!/, ja
r:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/framework-jaxb-11.2.6.ja
r!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/finacle-jaxb-11.2
.6.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/framework-ap
i-11.2.6.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/calcul
ations-api-11.2.6.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/l
ib/calculations-impl-11.2.6.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPS
HOT.jar!/lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNA
PSHOT.jar!/lib/febaData-11.2.6.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SN
APSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsService
s-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzTo
olsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:
/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar
!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-tx-4.2.5.RE
LEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-te
st-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/li
b/spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SN
APSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-expression-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsS
ervices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/Fi
nanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/F
inanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-oxm-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:
file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-orm-4.2.5.RELEASE.j
ar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-jdbc-4.2.
5.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/jmock
-junit3-2.5.1.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/j
mock-2.5.1.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/hamc
rest-core-1.3.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/h
amcrest-library-1.3.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!
/lib/jmock-junit4-2.5.1.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.
jar!/lib/junit-dep-4.4.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.j
ar!/lib/jmock-legacy-2.5.1.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSH
OT.jar!/lib/objenesis-1.0.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHO
T.jar!/lib/cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAP
SHOT.jar!/lib/junit-3.8.2.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHO
T.jar!/lib/hsqldb-1.8.0.7.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHO
T.jar!/lib/hibernate-ehcache-3.6.0.Final.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices
-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/ehcache-2.10.1.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices
-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.5.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices
-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/jaxb-xjc-2.2.5.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices
-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.5.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsService
s-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/ehcache-core-2.5.0.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsSer
vices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.0.Final.jar!/, jar:fi
le:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/cglib-2.2.jar!/, jar:file:/D
:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/asm-3.1.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/Finan
zToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/javassist-3.12.0.GA.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/
FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/integration-1.0.0.jar!/, jar:file:/
D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar!/, jar:f
ile:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar!/, jar:
file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/jstl-1.2.jar!/, jar:file:/
D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.10.jar!
/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/commons-dbcp-1.4.ja
r!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/commons-pool-1.6.
jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/jetty-server-9.
2.2.v20140723.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/j
avax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.j
ar!/lib/jetty-http-9.2.15.v20160210.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2
.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/jetty-io-9.2.15.v20160210.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsSe
rvices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/jetty-webapp-9.2.2.v20140723.jar!/, jar:file:/D:
/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/jetty-xml-9.2.15.v20160210.jar!/,
jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/jetty-servlet-9.2.15.v
20160210.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/jetty-
ant-9.2.2.v20140723.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!
/lib/ant-1.6.5.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/
ant-launcher-1.6.5.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/
lib/jetty-annotations-9.2.15.v20160210.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-1
1.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzTools
Services-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/asm-5.0.1.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServi
ces-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/asm-commons-5.0.1.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsSe
rvices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/asm-tree-5.0.1.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsSe
rvices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/jetty-plus-9.2.2.v20140723.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/F
inanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/jetty-jndi-9.2.2.v20140723.jar!/, ja
r:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/jetty-util-9.2.15.v20160
210.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/jetty-secur
ity-9.2.2.v20140723.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!
/lib/apache-jstl-9.2.2.v20140723.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-
SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/taglibs-standard-spec-1.2.1.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/FinanzToolsSer
vices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.1.jar!/, jar:file:/D:/F
inanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/jackson-databind-2.4.0.jar!/, jar:fi
le:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/jackson-core-2.4.0.jar!/, ja
r:file:/D:/FinanzToolsServices-11.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/jackson-annotations-2.4.
0.jar!/]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.Invocat
ionTargetException
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner
.java:62)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner
.java:54)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerExc
eption: Unable to start embedded Jetty servlet container
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletC
ontainer.start(JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.java:124)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationConte
xt.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:293)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationConte
xt.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refres
h(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationConte
xt.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.
java:766)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(Sp
ringApplication.java:361)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java
:307)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java
:1191)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java
:1180)
        at com.infosys.finanztools.Application.main(Application.java:13)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:27
7)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNet
workConnector.java:80)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java
:216)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLife
Cycle.java:68)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletC
ontainer.start(JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.java:118)
        ... 16 more
```

Comment: Post the full stack trace...

Comment: I have updated the full stacktrace

Comment: Also I have noted that the issue is not with 32 bit to 64 bit. I could make it work in one of the 64 bit computer without any changes. So it is  some issue with embeded container

Comment: The error message said: `Address already in use: bind`. This means the address (or port) that you want to use is already being used by other applications.

Comment: Thank you @LawrenceChoy for the quick help. I have not noticed that in the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue. The system which it is running is already have some other server running. So, the jetty container could not use the port allocated for it and throwing the exception "Address already in use: bind". Thank you @Lawrence Choy for pointing out the issues.